# AngularJs with ui.router how to set authenticate for its children

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

i'am using AngularJS with ui-router, this is my current app.js configuration.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('nodeserverApp', [
'ngCookies',
'ngResource',
'ngSanitize',
'ngRoute',
'ui.bootstrap',
'ui.router'
])
.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider , $stateProvider , $urlRouterProvider) {

$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'partials/user/main',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
    })
    .state('dashboard', {
        url: '/user/dashboard',
        templateUrl: 'partials/user/dashboard/main',
        controller: 'UserDashboardDashboardCtrl',
        authenticate: true
    })
    .state('dashboard.welcome', {
        url: '/welcome',
        parent: 'dashboard',
        templateUrl: 'partials/user/dashboard/welcome'
    })
    .state('dashboard.account', {
        url: '/account',
        templateUrl: 'partials/user/dashboard/account',
        controller: 'UserDashboardAccountCtrl'
    })
    .state('dashboard.address', {
        url: '/address',
        templateUrl: 'partials/user/dashboard/address/index'

    })
    .state('dashboard.address.view', {
        url: '/view',
        templateUrl: 'partials/user/dashboard/address/view',
        controller: 'UserDashboardAddressViewCtrl'

    })
    .state('dashboard.address.new', {
        url: '/new',
        templateUrl: 'partials/user/dashboard/address/new',
        controller: 'UserDashboardAddressNewCtrl'

    })
    .state('login', {
        url: '/user/login',
        templateUrl: 'partials/user/login',
        controller: 'LoginCtrl'
    })
    .state('signup', {
        url: '/user/signup',
        templateUrl: 'partials/user/signup',
        controller: 'SignupCtrl'
    })
    .state('settings', {
        url: '/user/settings',
        templateUrl: 'partials/user/settings',
        controller: 'SettingsCtrl',
        authenticate: true
    });

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

// Intercept 401s and 403s and redirect you to login
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q', '$location', function($q, $location) {
  return {
    'responseError': function(response) {
      if(response.status === 401 || response.status === 403) {
        $location.path('/user/login');
        return $q.reject(response);
      }
      else {
        return $q.reject(response);
      }
    }
  };
}]);
})
.run(function ($rootScope, $state, Auth) {
    $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
        if (toState.authenticate && !Auth.isLoggedIn()){
            // User isn’t authenticated
            $state.transitionTo("login");
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

as you can see, dashboard requires authentication, how can i make it's children inherit the authenticate like dashboard.welcome , dashboard.address.view etc. with out the need to specify each one?

Comment: Can you provide more information about how you are doing the authentication?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I know this is pretty old, but for future Googlers, note that the `data` property is inherited by child states, so you can place something like this `authenticate` flag in the parent. These modifications to your should do the trick:

For `$stateProvider`:

```
.state('dashboard', {
    url: '/user/dashboard',
    templateUrl: 'partials/user/dashboard/main',
    controller: 'UserDashboardDashboardCtrl',
    data: {
        authenticate: true
    }
})
```

For `angular.module`:

```
.run(function ($rootScope, $state, Auth) {
    $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
        if (toState.data.authenticate && !Auth.isLoggedIn()){
            // User isn’t authenticated
            $state.transitionTo("login");
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Please note `toState.data.authenticate` may throw a null pointer if your state isn't set up properly, using a checkNested method would be beneficial here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631001/javascript-test-for-existence-of-nested-object-key

Answer (score 2):

I hope this link will help, this is a great article from Frederik Nakstad about the Single Page Auth for AngularJS, sorry but not able to provide you the detail codes

http://frederiknakstad.com/2013/01/21/authentication-in-single-page-applications-with-angular-js/